# How can I dynamically add Include to ObjectSet<Entity> using C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to add `Include`s dynamically from input `params[]`. How can I do this?

This is my code

```
IQueryable<Work> query = this.ObjectContext.Works
    .Include("EmployeeSender.Person")
    .Include("EmployeeReceiver.Person")
    .Include("WorkCode")
    .Include("WorkFlowStep.WorkFlowFormState")
    .Include("WorkFlow")
    .Include("WorkRoot.EmployeeSender.Person")
    .Include("WorkParent");
```

Comment: delete this question as posted another

Comment: excuse me, send become duplicate non-intentional

Comment: yeah, thats why i pointed you that, I know it was by mistake, otherwise why one would post a double question within few seconds.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ query: Dynamically add Includes at run time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165969/linq-query-dynamically-add-includes-at-run-time)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In a loop, for example:

```
IQueryable<Work> query = null;  

query = this.ObjectContext.Works;
foreach (var param in params)
{
    query = query.Include(param);
}
var result = query.ToList();
```

As Christian Dietz mentioned, you can then put this in an extension method so that it becomes reusable.

Comment: in query.Include(param); this Error is raised. "'System.Linq.IQueryable<KhorasanMIS.Web.Entities.Work>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<KhorasanMIS.Web.Entities.Work>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: Include is an extension method declared in System.Data.Entity.DbExtensions. You're probably missing a using clause for the System.Data.Entity namespace.

Comment: thank you L-Tree, but my project is asp.net and Silverlight .probably this caused System.Linq.IQueryable<Entity> is different.

Comment: Include is defined in System.Data.Objects Namespace Inside System.Data.Entity.dll

Answer (score 3):

You can combine L-Three's answer with the extension method in the following question.

[Using .Include() when joining a view using Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976563/using-include-when-joining-a-view-using-entity-framework)

```
public static IQueryable<T> Include<T>(this IQueryable<T> sequence, params string[] includes) {
    var objectQuery = sequence as ObjectQuery<T>;
    if (objectQuery != null){
        foreach(item in includes){
             objectQuery.Include(item);
        }
        return objectQuery;
    }
    return sequence;
}
```

Then you should be able to use include like:

```
IQueryable<Work> query = null;  

query = this.ObjectContext.Works.Include("Something", "Whatever");
```

Answer (score 3):

Lazy loading is not yet possible with EF Core. [Refer here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data).

Alternatively you can use eager loading.

Read this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366236/lazy-loading-vs-eager-loading)

Below is the extension method i have created to achieve the eager loading.

Extension Method:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> IncludeMultiple<TEntity, TProperty>(
            this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
            List<Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>>> navigationPropertyPath) where TEntity : class
        {
            foreach (var navExpression in navigationPropertyPath)
            {
                source= source.Include(navExpression);
            }
            return source.AsQueryable();
        }
```

Repository Call:

```
public async Task<TEntity> FindOne(ISpecification<TEntity> spec)
        {
            return await Task.Run(() => Context.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable().IncludeMultiple(spec.IncludeExpression()).Where(spec.IsSatisfiedBy).FirstOrDefault());
        }
```

Usage:

```
List<object> nestedObjects = new List<object> {new Rules()};

            ISpecification<Blog> blogSpec = new BlogSpec(blogId, nestedObjects); 

            var challenge = await this._blogRepository.FindOne(blogSpec);
```

Dependencies:

```
public class BlogSpec : SpecificationBase<Blog>
    {
        readonly int _blogId;
        private readonly List<object> _nestedObjects;

        public ChallengeSpec(int blogid, List<object> nestedObjects)
        {
            this._blogId = blogid;
            _nestedObjects = nestedObjects;
        }

        public override Expression<Func<Challenge, bool>> SpecExpression
        {
            get { return blogSpec => blogSpec.Id == this._blogId; }
        }

        public override List<Expression<Func<Blog, object>>> IncludeExpression()
        {
            List<Expression<Func<Blog, object>>> tobeIncluded = new List<Expression<Func<Blog, object>>>();
            if (_nestedObjects != null)
                foreach (var nestedObject in _nestedObjects)
                {
                    if (nestedObject is Rules)
                    {
                        Expression<Func<Blog, object>> expr = blog => blog.Rules;
                        tobeIncluded.Add(expr);
                    }

                }

            return tobeIncluded;
        }
```

Will be glad if it helps. Please note this is not a production ready code.